# Bind a List variable in a Dynamic SOQL Query

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

**Code 1**

```
List<String> accNameList = new List<String>{'Acc1','Acc2','Acc3'};
List<Account> accountList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name IN:accNameList');
```

**Code 2**

```
List<String> accNameList = new List<String>{'Acc1','Acc2','Acc3'}
List<Account> accountList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name IN (\''+String.join(accNameList,'\',\'')+'\')')
```

The two codes above are equivalent (return the same list of accounts)

Beside of using the bind list variable to prevent any flaw of **SOQL Injection**

Is there a performance reason (or other reason) than the one cited **?**

Comment: Using a List of string would be definitely faster as there is it would take some time in constructing String.join

Comment: @RahulSharma Thank you for that note, but want to know if there is a performance reason in the SOQL execution

Comment: @beham you should use profiling for this scenario. The developer console can give you pretty good information on the performance.

Comment: "Code 2" will also fail if one of the names includes a single quote character. Also its pretty difficult to read ad confirm that "Code 2" even adds the quotes correctly. Personally, I would always use the "Code 1" pattern. (Before considering performance, see [Premature Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) for some perspective.)

Comment: @KeithC yes I know, but I can still, escape the quotes with String.escapteSingleQuote() the purpose of the question is to know if there is a performance reason to use bind variable, I checked the performance see the results in the answers ...

Comment: @benahm Please read the link I provided about premature optimisation. Three years from now a developer maintaining your code will thank you much more for clarity and simplicity than tiny variations in performance.

Comment: @KeithC Thank you, you're right. but trust me, I am in case that I have to use the code 2, that's why I am worried about performance. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, do the following:

> 1. Open your developer console.
> 2. Execute on Code 1.
> 3. Under the Log tab,
> 4. double click on the last execution of code 1.
> 5. Debug-> View Log Panels
> 6. Select Stack Tree

That will allow you to check Duration and Heap on the tab **Performance Tree**. This tab is on the Stack Tree panel.

Do the same for the Code 2 and compare.

Comment: Nice, thanks @carlos, I was looking for the same as well! :)

Comment: You welcome guys. I think it is a very fast and easy way to check performances.

Answer (score 1):

Followed the steps suggested by @Carlos (in his [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/164125/41226)) to compare the performance of the two codes on the Developer Console

Below the results

*(Tested using lists containing many values the Code 2 is always faster but uses more Heap space)*

**Code 1**

[image: Code 1]

**Code 2**

[image: Code 2]