# How to bind list of string in dynamic SOQL

Tags: soql, list, dynamic-soql

```
    List<String> cityList = Label.cityNames.split(',');
    String SOQL = 'Select id, name from Account where city IN:cityList'

    Databse.executeQuery(SOQL);
```

Could you please correct the above query to bind the list into SOQL.

The above dynamic SOQL is working fine if I pass `new List<String> {'A','B','C'}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind a List variable in a Dynamic SOQL Query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164117/bind-a-list-variable-in-a-dynamic-soql-query)

Comment: @glls in my scenario the list values are dynamic.

Comment: also [How to execute a dynamic SOQL query with a variable number of “in” terms?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32478/how-to-execute-a-dynamic-soql-query-with-a-variable-number-of-in-terms?rq=1)

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message? If so, please **[edit]** your post to include it...

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard field name called "City", it should be BillingCity or ShippingCity. Check with below query and use Database.Query instead Database.ExecuteQuery

```
List<String> cityList = Label.cityNames.split(',');
system.debug('--- cityList ---'+cityList);
String strQuery = 'Select id, name from Account where Billingcity IN:cityList';
List<Account> lstAccount = Database.query(strQuery);
system.debug('--- lstAccount ---'+lstAccount);
```